# How to run single spec2 test with maven?

Tags: scala, maven, spec2

I have a scala class with several spec2 tests in it and maven as build tool. I can't find how I can launch one single spec2 test using maven. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Did you take a look here: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Via+Maven ?

Comment: thanks @mfirry, I can see there that I can `execute specifications as [JUnit test cases](#Via JUnit).` if I don't have spec2 maven plugin. And it seems to me like it implies that I can filter the tests I don't want to run and I wasn't able to do it